# Differences between Flash and HTML5

Tags: html, flash, adobe

Since Youtube has dropped flash for HTML5, what exactly are the qualities/utilities that HTML5 possesses that makes it different than flash?

Also, I wish to know something more interesting(conceptually/technically) about the same (apart from what the normal google search is showing).

Comment: In short, flash is a plugin that has its own code to run a video, which needs to be downloaded and installed, for HTML5 that code resides in the browser, nothing to install. HTML5 pro's: easier to code media web sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can read up on the Wikipedia Article on the comparisons between the two [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML5_and_Flash)

I've taken these sentences from about half way down the page

Regarding **Flash**

> Web browsers cannot render Flash media themselves, instead it is
>   rendered primarily via the proprietary but freely available Adobe
>   Flash Player.

Regarding **HTML5**

> All web browsers support HTML and other Web standards to various
>   degree. Adobe released a tool that converts Flash to HTML5, and in
>   June 2011, Google released an experimental tool that does the same.

Like I said about the Wiki Article gives a better comparison